# Does a tool exist to merge multiple things in a table at once?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve, arctoolbox

Is there a tool that can merge specific things in a table at once?

The problem I currently have is that I have about 110 different features in a table and all of them have another entry with the same name that I want to merge together.

I know I can merge them one at a time but I am wondering if a tool exists that can automate this.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of data you have? Do I understand this correctly? This is one shapefile that contains 110 features. The attribute table contains at least one column/field called `NAME`. Every feature has the same name. You want to merge all features into one feature?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you will want to look for the `Dissolve` tool. I apologize, but I do not have access to Arcgis-desktop. In QGIS this is how I would do it. I would imagine that Arc would have something very similar.

**Step 1**

Here is a shapefile that contains a `id` and `NAME` field.
[image]

**Step 2**

Use the Vector Dissolve tool
[image]

**Step 3**

Make sure you select the column that you want to dissolve to. In this case I choose `NAME`.
[image]

**Step 4**

Here are your results. Because I had two different names, I ended up with two different features. If you had one name, you would end up with one feature.
[image]

Comment: Yes, ArcGIS has a [Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) tool.  The tool dialog is a little different but they do the same job.

Comment: @ChilledReay if this answers your question, could you please mark it correct?